# PowerShell : Getting Node value from selected xml

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following XML. I want to get the value of the `Version` node (which is `1.0.0.0`) using PowerShell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportExportXml version="9.2.23105.230" >
  <SolutionManifest>
    <UniqueName>ShowandTell</UniqueName>
    <LocalizedNames>
      <LocalizedName description="Show and Tell" languagecode="1033" />
    </LocalizedNames>
    <Descriptions />
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Managed>0</Managed>    
  </SolutionManifest>
</ImportExportXml>
```

So far I have tried, with below

```
$myVar = Select-Xml -Path "C:\Coding\Solution.xml" -XPath "//Version"
```

when I print `$myVar` I get the following,

[image]

However, I am after the value of the `Version` tag in preferably non-tabular format. I also tried `Get-Content` but with a similar sort of outcome,

```
$myVar = Get-Content -Path "C:\Coding\Solution.xml"
```

Then `$myVar.ImportExportXml.SolutionManifest.Version` does not return any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there under the node property:

```
$myvar = Select-Xml -XPath //Version -Path solution.xml 
$myvar.node.'#text'

1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Nice. `$myvar.Node.InnerText` works too.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-8.0) and [`SelectSingleNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-8.0) you can get the value of `Version` with:

```bash
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load('C:\Coding\Solution.xml')
$xml.SelectSingleNode('/ImportExportXml/SolutionManifest').Version
```

Using `Select-Xml` you can get it using:

```bash
Select-Xml -Path C:\Coding\Solution.xml -XPath /ImportExportXml/SolutionManifest |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Version }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using the `//` in XPath:

```
(Select-XMl -Path 'C:\Coding\Solution.xml' -Xpath '//SolutionManifest' | Select-Object -EXpandProperty Node ).Version
```

or, when you need the languagecode

```
(Select-XMl -Path 'C:\Coding\Solution.xml' -Xpath '//LocalizedNames' | Select-Object -EXpandProperty Node ).LocalizedName.languagecode
```